# how to render google site in object

Tags: html, iframe

you can embed whatever web site in a iframe:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.chercherecole.com"/>
</body>
</html>
```

but if I try with Google it doesnt work:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems Google may have activated  X-Frame-Options response header, so the question is

could i use other element to render google page in my web site? Perhaps using object ?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use server side script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems Google may have activated X-Frame-Options response header

Yes.

> so the question is could i use other element to render google page in my web site? Perhaps using object ?

No. They will also respect `X-Frame-Options`.